# Function field, show date field as text - OpenERP v7

Tags: python, xml, odoo, openerp-7

So far I'm trying to get a date field data, translated into text format in OpenERP v7.

I made a function on `stock` module, but when I declare this on my `xml` view, it returns `Undefined` tag, and I can't group line by date anymore.

This is my code:

```
    def _date_(self, cr, uid, ids, fields, arg, context):
    x={}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids):
        if record.create_date :
            a = date.strptime(record.create_date, "%Y-%m-%d")
            b = a.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            x[record.id] = text(b(a))
        return x

    _columns = {
        'create_date': fields.date('Creation Date', readonly=True, select=True),
        'date_': fields.function(_date_, type='text', string='date copy', store=True),
```

And on `stock_view.xml`

```
<filter string="Creation" name="groupby_create_date" icon="terp-go-month" domain="[]" context="{'group_by':'date_'}"
```

It doesn't actually group them, but show 'undefined' tag, and groups all lines without discrimination by month, which is the normal behavior of `create_date` date type field, so, how can I achieve this?

I'm making some tests, but I don't see any change on it.

Can someone please shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'date_': fields.function(*date*, **type='date'**, string='date copy', store=True)

x[record.id] = text(b(a))

and not convert date in text type

Hope this help

Comment: Hi, thank you, but I need to convert the date into text, and group lines by that text, it should work as the original filter, but in text format, it's still 'undefined'...

Comment: I applied your changes but I'm afraid it's not really text though, or I don't know... I need this because of this module https://bitbucket.org/anybox/web_d3_chart/ , this module has the problem that everytime I group on date or datetime format it throws an error, so I really need to convert date or datetime into text.

Comment: Ok, your answer is right, it's actually a concept problem, I should modify the original module, or change the concept completely, thank you very much!